# In cypress testing how to check if these cards are in order?

Tags: javascript, cypress

[image]

As shown in the image there are multiple chapters with chapter number, not in proper order right now. I want a test in cypress that checks if chapter numbers are in order. In case they get shuffled (as shown in image), the test should show an error.

One solution is checking every chapter card like:

```
cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .jss90').should('contain', 'Chapter Number 1')
cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .jss90').should('contain', 'Chapter Number 2')
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .jss90').should('contain', 'Chapter Number 3')
...
```

But the issue is there are lots of chapters and I can't do it for each and every card. What I want is something like card 2 > card 1. Card 3 > card 2 and so on based on chapter numbers. For example, first 2 cards are correct as Chapter 8 > Chapter 5 but next 2 will give error as Chapter 1 < Chapter 8. So is there a way to check if next card has bigger chapter number than previous card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to shorten the code using string templates.

Make sure you use back-ticks around the strings.

```js
Cypress._.times(7, (index) => {
  cy.get(`:nth-child(${index}) > .jss90`)
    .should('contain', `Chapter Number ${index}`)
})
```

Comment: it says `Cypress.time is not a function`

Comment: Oops that should be `Cypress._.times(`